# Conditional expectation and indicator function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, wiener-measure

Is there a simple way of computing the following
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathrm{E}(S_T\mathbf{1}_{S_T>X}|S_t=s)
\end{equation}
(here $S_t$ follows a Geometric Brownian Motion) with $t<T$?
My idea was to split the conditioned probabilities, but I guess it doesn’t make it simple, for $S_T$ and $\mathbf{1}_{S_T>X}$ aren’t independent.

Comment: You can do a change of measure

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you mean a Wiener measure?

Comment: I meant this technique https://benjaminwhiteside.com/2022/09/04/girsanovs-theorem/  which is well known in quantitative finance. But now, I think that for your question, perhaps a easier way is to just express $S_T$ into a function of $W_T$ (which follow $\mathcal{N}(0,T)$) and compute the expectation as an integral of $W_T$

Comment: What is the given $X$?

Comment: It's just a constant

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is no drift, then
$$S_T= S_t\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)+\sigma (W_T-W_t)  \right)$$
We have
$$\begin{align}
L&:= \mathbb{E}\left( S_T  \mathbf{1}_{\{S_T>X\}} | S_t\right) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left( S_t\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)+\sigma (W_T-W_t)  \right)  \mathbf{1}_{\left\{   W_T - W_t> \ln\left( \frac{S_t}{X} \right)+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)  \right\}} |S_t \right) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left( S_0\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)+\sigma \sqrt{T-t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(0,1) \right)  \mathbf{1}_{\left\{   \mathcal{N}(0,1)> \frac{\ln\left( \frac{S_t}{X} \right)+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)}{\sqrt{T-t}}  \right\}} |S_t\right) \\
\end{align}$$
Denote $a=\frac{\ln\left( \frac{S_t}{X} \right)+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)}{\sqrt{T-t}} $, then
$$
L = S_t\cdot e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t) }\int_{a}^{+\infty}e^{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}\cdot x }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx
$$
I let you do a change or variable and compute the integral. It's not difficult.

Comment: You've calculated the expectation, but I need the conditional one. Is it the same?

Comment: Generally speaking,  $E(X\mid A)=\frac{E(1_AX)}{\Pr(A)}$, but in his case $\Pr(S_t=s)$ is a delta function

Comment: @ric.san  Due to the markovian property of the process $S_t$, the conditional expectation is computed by the same formula. I changed my answer $S_0 \rightarrow S_t$

Comment: @ric.san a more elegant way for more complex problem is to use Girsanov's theorem and do a change of measure to eliminate the term $S_T$ in the (conditional) expectation as I said before.